# How to Update a File in Sharepoint's Layouts Folder

Tags: sharepoint, layout

I have a masterpage that uses a js file in the layouts folder.  I want to manually edit this file for development purposes, but my browser does not get the latest copy if I manually open the layouts folder and edit the file.  I tried doing a hard refresh on the client-side with CTRL+F5, but I still get the old copy.

Is there an easy way to edit this file without redeploying my masterpage feature over and over again?

Comment: have you tried recycling IIS after the file is updated?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to redeploy it. You need to clear the browser cache. If you open it from another browser, or if you clear the browser's history, you'll see you don't need to redeploy it.

Comment: I tried clearing my cache, and even adding a new version after the js file name (e.g. file.js?rev=123).  Neither of those work.  I also tried creating a new file in the layouts folder and accessing it through my browser, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: @user1938132 Inspect the element or view the page source and follow the link of the js file. Trust me it's just the browser, I had the same problem with a css stylesheet and it didn't change even after I redeployed the project (I was using Chrome).